# Задать выборку по значению поля без учета регистра

Tags: mysql, mysqli

При выборке, mysql учитывает регистр? Если да, возможно поправить это?

Comment: Учёт регистра целиком и полностью определяет COLLATION. Который может быть регистрозависимым (`CS`) и регистронезависимым (`CI`). Читать [Character Sets, Collations, Unicode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html) до полного понимания.

Answer (score 0):

В обычной MariaDB не учитывается, а вот, например, в oracle учитывается